# Is there a source/cookbook of equations that approximate geometric shapes?

Tags: approximation, geometry

I'm numerically modelling flows around various geometric 2D shapes. Is there a good source/cookbook of equations that approximate these? Some examples are

1. Rectangle:
   $(x-a)^n+(y-b)^n < r^n$  where $r$ is side length and $n$ is even. The larger $n$, the sharper the corners.
   Also e.g. $\text{max}(500 (x-a), 55 (y-b)) < r^2$ achieves this .
2. Tilted square:
   $(x-a)+(y-b) < r^2$
3. Bullet:
   $(-x+1.2a)^{1.7}+(y-b)^2 < r^2$

Comment: You can explore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_curves

Comment: I am creating a community post for this.

Answer (score 2):

Following there are some resources that might be useful.

- Wikipedia has a [List of curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_curves). They are listed according to some classification criteria and link to the article of each curve, where you can further read.
- Shikin, E. V. (1995). Handbook and atlas of curves. CRC Press. This books presents an atlas where the curves are listed in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thanks, Shikin has a few useful entries. Still a bit thin on the curves of interest, i.e. closed, bounded, mainly convex and, especially, approximations for  polygons.

Comment: @Friasco You should check MathMod, it has some interesting ones.